# Console app works on Windows, doesn't on Linux with Mono

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I am developing a simple TCP server. To communicate with its clients I use the `StreamWriter` class, like so:

```
client.ClientWriter.WriteLine(command);
client.ClientWriter.Flush();
```

The command is a single word, followed by the line terminator `System.Environment.NewLine`. My client (written in Lua) checks for the command like this:

```
if data:find("INIT") then DoSomething()
elseif data:find("START") then DoSomethingElse()
...
else SendResponse("BAD REQUEST")
```

I developed the original app using VS2017. When I run it on a Windows machine, the app works perfectly.

However, I need to deploy my app to Linux running Mono. When I tested the app on Linux, every command I sent to the client was not recognized and `"BAD REQUEST"` was returned. I could not reproduce the problem on my Windows machine.

EDIT: After some testing, I am able to run the program on Kubuntu running mono 4.2.1; but I still can't run it on my other machine (the one I need to deploy on) running mono 4.2.3.

What could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: The lines terminators could be responsible of this. On Windows it is "\r\n" on Unix it is simply "\n".

Comment: Always use `System.Environemt.NewLine` in C# to avoid errors like this.

Comment: Have you checked what you LUA client actually receives (commonly referred to as "debugging")?

Comment: @John-Philip @waka I have changed the way I look for strings, it is now `data:find("INIT")`. I have also implemented `System.Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer yes, it receives correct strings but fails to recognise them for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this problem was only a symptom of something bigger. I perform reading commands from a Task. Mono that I use (version 4.1.3) apparently has a bug that prevents some Tasks from starting, so I explicitly declared a Thread instead.